# Only 1 marker is getting removed from Google maps in Angular/Ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, google-maps-markers

I am using Google Maps in an Ionic/Angular app and am having trouble deleting markers. I am using 
    https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

as a guide but am having trouble. In the app, 1 marker gets laced when the user taps on the map (this is in the initialise function). Another marker gets placed when getResult() is called. When I try to clear the markers, I'm not able to remove the one that is placed by tapping on the map. But the other marker gets removed. I'm not sure why this is happening. Any advice?

```
  $scope.initialise = function() {

    $ionicLoading.show({
            content: 'Loading',
            animation: 'fade-in',
            showBackdrop: true,
            maxWidth: 200,
            showDelay: 0,
            duration: 5000
          });

            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.758446, -122.411789);
            $scope.markersArray = [];

            //Initial settings for the map
            var mapOptions = {
                    center: myLatlng,
                    zoom: 2,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    styles: [{ featureType: "poi", elementType: "labels", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]}]

                };

            //Load the initial map
             var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions); 


            //Event listener to add a marker      
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {

              $scope.clearOverlays();
              $scope.coordinates = e.latLng;
              $scope.placeMarker(e.latLng, $scope.map);

            });

            //Actual function to add a marker
            $scope.placeMarker = function(position, map) {

              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map
              });

              $scope.markersArray.push(marker);

              map.panTo(position);

            }

            $scope.clearOverlays = function() { 

              for (var i = 0; i < $scope.markersArray.length; i++ ) {
                $scope.markersArray[i].setMap(null);
              }
              $scope.markersArray = [];
            }

            $scope.map=map;

      $ionicLoading.hide(); 

      };
      // End of initialise

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', $scope.initialise());


  $scope.getResult = function() {
            // Add actual coordinates to map
        actualCoor = new google.maps.LatLng(Number($scope.active_location.Lat), Number($scope.active_location.Long));
        $scope.placeMarker(actualCoor, $scope.map);

      // Resize the map
        window.setTimeout(function(){
          google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        },100);

        // Add actual coordinates to map
        actualCoor = new google.maps.LatLng(Number($scope.active_location.Lat), Number($scope.active_location.Long));
        $scope.placeMarker(actualCoor, $scope.map);

        // Resize the map
        window.setTimeout(function(){
          $scope.map.panTo($scope.coordinates);
        },100);

        // Add circle overlay to map
        $scope.circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          map: $scope.map,
          center: actualCoor,
          radius: 500000,  //500km away
          strokeColor:"#0000FF",
          strokeOpacity:0.8,
          strokeWeight:2,
          fillColor:"#0000FF",
          fillOpacity:0.4
        });

        // Add line between points
        var flightPlanCoordinates = [$scope.coordinates, actualCoor];
        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: flightPlanCoordinates,
          geodesic: true,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 2
        });
        flightPath.setMap($scope.map);


        // Show info window for user's guess 
        $scope.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'Your guess'
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: $scope.coordinates,
          map: $scope.map,
          title: 'Your guess'
        });

        $scope.infowindow.open($scope.map,marker);
  }

    $scope.reset_map = function() {



        console.log($scope.markersArray[0]);
        $scope.markersArray[0].setMap(null);
        console.log($scope.markersArray[0]);

        console.log($scope.markersArray[1]);
        $scope.markersArray[1].setMap(null);
        console.log($scope.markersArray[1]);

        $scope.markersArray = [];

        // Remove line
        flightPath.setMap(null);

        // Remove circle
        $scope.circle.setMap(null);

        // Remove infowindow
        $scope.infowindow.close();
        $scope.infowindow = null;

        // $scope.clearOverlays();


      }
```

I am pretty sure this is happening because I'm adding the infowindow and marker to show on load, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: My guess: `$scope.getResult` adds 2 Markers on the same place (you have duplicated code), so your `clear` code might be clearing only the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You are not pushing the marker you create for the Infowindow to the markersArray.That's why its not getting removed.Just add these lines.

```
$scope.markersArray.push(marker); // Add this line
$scope.infowindow.open($scope.map,marker);
```